# Changing image source based on date

Tags: javascript, date

What I'm trying to do is change a landing page image based on the month and day. Trouble is when I implement this code I get an error, here's the code:

```
function kblogo() { 
var d = new Date();
var Today = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
var logoSrc;
if (Month == 10 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
    logoSrc = "Images/doodles/KBThanksgiving.png";
} else if (Month == 11 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
    logoSrc = "Images/doodles/KBHolidays.png";
} else if ((Month == 11 && Today >= 30) || (Month == 0 && Today <= 2)) {
    logoSrc = "Images/doodles/KBNewYear.png";
} else if (Month == 6 && (Today >= 3 && Today <= 5)) {
    logoSrc = "Images/doodles/KBJuly4.png";
} else {
    logoSrc = "Images/KB.png";
}
document.getElementById("kbLogo").src = logoSrc;
}
```

Just changed the code to this I'll be testing it shortly. Any idea's let me know.

I've run it through some different validators and found different things and fixed them but it's as fixed as I have gotten it and it still crashes IE and FF when I implement it.

```
<img id="Logo" src="Images/default.png" alt="KnowledgeBase" width="75%" onload="logo()" />
```

Above is the requested img tag

Comment: Please *always* specify what error you are getting and where

Comment: You should just call "getElementById()" once, and save the reference in a variable. It's wasteful to have all those calls, and error prone - one of yours, in fact, uses a different string than the others.

Comment: What's `kbLogo`? We need more information here.

Comment: So Pointy I would want something like "var logo = document.getElementById("Logo").src" and then inside the if statements write "logo = 'whatever/image/path'"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logo function is looping - also no need to load default if default is already loaded

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gLffJ/)

```
<img id="Logo" src="Images/default.png" alt="KnowledgeBase" width="75%" onload="logo(this)" />


function logo(img) {
  if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src;
  if (Month === 10 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
    src = "Images/doodles/blah1.png";
  } else if (Month === 11 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
    src = "Images/doodles/blah2.png";
  } else if ((Month === 11 && Today >= 30) || (Month === 0 && Today <= 2)) {
    src = "Images/doodles/blah3.png";
  } else if (Month === 6 && (Today >= 3 && Today <= 5)) {
    src = "Images/doodles/blah4.png";
  } 
  img.src=src;
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this as you've got it here and for some reason it still fails to change the image. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that it's being implemented inside a wordpress page. I've used other javascript functions to do things like this but this specific function refuses to run.

Comment: I take it all back! This solution worked perfectly but for those that don't know wordpress will not allow you to put the javascript in the post it needs to be applied in the header (unless there's some plugin that allows all that to happen that I'm not aware of). Once the code was in the header it all worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

First.
Your `<img>` has `id="Logo"`, but in code you write `document.getElementById("kbLogo")`

Second.
Your `<img>` has `src="mages/default.png"`, but in code you use `"Images/default.png";`

Comment: lol I was trying to edit things so that I didn't expose any used variables but I'm short on sleep let me fix that

Answer (score 0):

What the error is?

See you have 'Logo' and 'kbLogo' image ID. 
Not really important but, why use the === operand instead == ?

Remember Month=10 meand November instead October.

I tested next code and works for me:

```
var d = new Date();
var Today = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
if (Month == 10 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26) ) {
    console.log("Images/doodles/blah1.png");
} else if (Month == 11 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26) ) {
    console.log("Images/doodles/blah2.png");
} else if ( (Month == 11 && Today >= 30) || (Month == 0 && Today <= 2) ) {
    console.log("Images/doodles/blah3.png");
} else if (Month == 6 && (Today >= 3 && Today <= 5) ) {
    console.log("Images/doodles/blah4.png");
} else {
    console.log("Images/default.png");
}
```

Comment: === This is the strict equal operator and only returns a Boolean true if both the operands are equal and of the same type

Comment: @Neil: date.getXXX returns ints so === can be safely used