# Automatically change the picture by month with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask the question.

Well I would like to use a script which automatically changes the picture of my start site of my website. So the script should check the month and if the month is march it uses picture1.jpg and if the month is august it uses picture2.jpg.

Is it possible to do that, e.g. using javascript?

I am looking forward to your answer(s) and would love it if you could help me creating such a script.

Thank you!

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. A search on SO or google would have been more apprpriate.

Comment: I know this. But nevertheless I hope that I can get the help I need here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample and can be modified code:

```
<img id="Logo" src="Images/default.png" alt="KnowledgeBase" width="75%" onload="logo(this)" />


    function logo(img) {
      if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
      var d = new Date();
      var Today = d.getDate();
      var Month = d.getMonth();
      var src;
      if (Month === 10 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
        src = "Images/doodles/blah1.png";
      } else if (Month === 11 && (Today >= 23 && Today <= 26)) {
        src = "Images/doodles/blah2.png";
      } else if ((Month === 11 && Today >= 30) || (Month === 0 && Today <= 2)) {
        src = "Images/doodles/blah3.png";
      } else if (Month === 6 && (Today >= 3 && Today <= 5)) {
        src = "Images/doodles/blah4.png";
      } 
      img.src=src;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gLffJ/)

Alternative:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
var months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'); 
var thetime = new Date(); 
var themonth = thetime.getMonth(); 
document.write('<img src="image' + months[themonth] + '.gif" alt="Image of the month: ' + months[themonth] + '" />'); 
</script>
```

Alternative 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner-container" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>

<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/winter.png')";
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage="url('images/fall.png')";
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/winter.png')";
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/spring.png')";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("banner-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/summer.png')";
}
</script>

</body> </html>
```

More info: [Changing image source based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247893/changing-image-source-based-on-date)

Comment: Which date is set at the first part?